# SSIS Get files from multiple subfolders

Tags: ssis, ftp

How to retrieve files from multiple FTP subfolders?

I have next structure:

1. mainFolder

   2. subFolder 1 -> File 1, File 2, File ... (more then 100 subfolders)

      3. subfolder 2 -> File 1, File 2, File ... (more then 100 folders)

         4. subfolder 2 -> File 1, File 2, File ... (more then 100 folders)

I found next  answer

> One approach would be to put each of your source folders in variables within your package. This would allow you to set up a Loop Container for each variable and pass each path in as a parameter to your ftp task. There would be some overhead because you would be building and destroying the ftp connection with each loop, but that would get you to a parameterized solution.

But I cannot *"put each of your source folders in variables within your package"*.

Can somebody show me how to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options you can look for is using Script Task to perform this. Script Task is one of those ingenious things embedded in SSIS that can do anything that out-of-the box components do not provide by taking full advantage of .Net libraries.

Here is a link that gives a explanation on how to do it - 
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/foreach-ftp-file-enumerator.html

Comment: Where in thу code presented on the link you gave  I can use the .Net variable folderNames to create some recursive function to loop through all subfolders

Answer (score 0):

If the SSIS FTP task cannot download a folder recursively (I do not know, but it looks like, as you are asking), just use the *Execute Process* task to start an external scriptable FTP client that can do this.

Most FTP clients can download folders recursively (with a notable exception of Windows built-in command-line FTP client).

You can use for example [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/). There's a guide for [using WinSCP with SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*